# App crashes if setting detailTextLabel of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, detailtextlabel

I'd like to set a value in the datailTextLabel of a UITableViewCell. If the code runs, the app crashes.

This is the error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

This is the method in which the error takes place:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "Date"      //error occurs

    return cell
}
```

Possible useful informations:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/240sy3k1ic2hu0q/Bildschirmfoto%202015-02-28%20um%2021.03.35.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

Also, there is no need to force unwrap it. Even if `detailTextLabel` exists, I would use `cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Date"` to be safe and make sure your cell is a style that supports `detailTextLabel`. Ie. Detail Left, Detail Right, Subtitle.

Comment: I'm not using storyboard. How can I change the style programmatically?

Comment: `UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")` Although there is more setup for creating a cell programmatically, but there are resources online for finding that